# ModelForm has no model class specified How can I connect model&form?

Tags: python, html, django

I got an error,ValueError at /accounts/upload_save/
ModelForm has no model class specified.
I wrote in forms.py

```
class UserImageForm(forms.ModelForm):
    owner = forms.CharField(max_length=20)
    image = forms.FileField()
```

in models.py

```
class ImageAndUser(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey("auth.User", verbose_name="imageforegin")
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='images', null=True, blank=True,)
```

in views.py

```
@csrf_exempt
def upload_save(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = UserImageForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            data = UserImageForm()
            data.owner = forms.cleaned_data['user']
            data.image = request.FILES['image']
            data.save()
        else:
            print(form.errors)
    else:
        form = UserImageForm()

    return render(request, 'registration/accounts/photo.html', {'form': form})
```

in index.html

```
<form action="{% url 'accounts:upload_save' %}" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        {% csrf_token %}

        <div class="input-group">
          <label class="input-group-btn">
            <span class="btn btn-primary btn-lg">
            <input type="file" style="display:none" name="files[]" multiple>
            </span>
          </label>
          <input type="text" class="form-control" readonly="">
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
        <input type="hidden" value="{{ p_id }}" name="p_id" class="form-control">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
        <input type="submit" value="SEND" class="form-control">
        </div>
      </form>
```

When I put SEND button, upload_save method is read.And my ideal system is image& user's data put in ImageAndUser model.What is wrong in my codes?How can I connect model&form?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
class UserImageForm(forms.ModelForm):
    owner = forms.CharField(max_length=20)
    image = forms.FileField()
```

that isn't the way to refer a model the correct way is :

```
class UserImageForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = ImageAndUser
```

and in the views:

```
form = UserImageForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            data = form.save(commit=False)#or just save if you dont need modify anything
            data.owner = forms.cleaned_data['user']
            data.image = request.FILES['image']
            data.save()
```

for more information read this https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/forms/modelforms/